# Laravel 5.2 HasThrough

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to access a users notes through their accounts. Basically the notes dont belong to the user, they belong to the account incase a user leaves the notes are still associated with an account.

Doing so is kind of difficult to build a query for.

Here is how it works:

`Users->Distributors->Accounts->Notes`

Where users have many `Distributors` (local key `id` foreign key is `user_id`). 
`Distributors` have many `accounts` (local key `vip_id` foreign key is `dist_abbv`). And `Accounts` have many `Notes` (local key `id` foreign key is `account_id`).

How the heck do I return just the notes?

Answer (score 1):

This can be acheived with [Nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). This gives the notes of each user.

```
$users=User::with('distributors','distributors.accounts,'accounts.notes')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
   foreach($user->distributors as $distributor)
      {
            foreach($distributor->accounts as $account)
             {
                  foreach($account->notes as $note)
                    {
                        print_r($note);
                    }
             }
     }
}
```

Comment: Seems to make sense. I should mention this is in my User model since I only want them for that logged in user. So I tried `$this->with('distributors','distributors.accounts','accounts.notes')->get()` and get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::accounts()`

Comment: @Packy for logged in user to get the notes you can add where condition `->where(['id'=>Auth::user()->id])->get();`